# Change a single line of text field to rich text?

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, rich-text, encoding, links

I am having this issue: [SharePoint 2013 - Custom View linkToItem=“TRUE” - Prevent Character Encoding in Link Text](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166155/sharepoint-2013-custom-view-linktoitem-true-prevent-character-encoding-in)

It sounds like I need to change the field to rich text.  The field currently is a "Single line of text"  Data-wise it is a simple one-line string and the field should not allow more than one line of text, nor should it support fancy text formatting.  The only things I've found on rich text is for "Multiple lines of text" fields.

How can I set this field to rich text, without the editors allowing multiple lines of text or fancy formatting?  Or is there another way to get the text to properly decode when shown in a link?  I'm hoping there is a less ugly way to do this than using javascript after the page load to fix the field.

In case it is useful, here are the relevant parts of the web part schema:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ... >
    <ParameterBindings>
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue="" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
        <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
    <DataFields>
    </DataFields>
    <XmlDefinition>
        <View ... >
            <Query>
                <OrderBy>
                    <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
                </OrderBy>
            </Query>
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name="Edit"/>
                <FieldRef Name="AccountName" linkToItem="TRUE" /> <!-- This is the column-->
                ...
            </ViewFields>
            <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
            <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
            <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
            <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
            <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
        </View>
    </XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

Comment: You can set number of rows to 1. But you will still get the editor thing.